# colorbox close button image not showing completely on repositioning

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

i am using a background image for the close button and i want it to appear as in the pic shown in the below link
http://www.jacklmoore.com/demo/modal/modal2.html
i was able to re position it to the top right corner easily using

```
#cboxClose{
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0; 
    right:0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    background:url(../images/modals/close-icon.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
    width:40px; 
    height:40px; 
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

Applying -ve top and right margins do not work.  The image just gets cut.

Could anyone please suggest how to do the same using the plugin.

Comment: Does your box opening in iFrame ?

Comment: Did not try that. Looks like something that can be achieved through CSS but somehow not evident.

Comment: If there is iFrame then you could not achieve this. Can you provide html as well here ?